# Problem with "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key" in tfs site server

Tags: c#, git, tfs, microsoft-teams

I have a problem with my site TFS when I click on my project on site:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

[image: this is image error]

I tried to find a solution to fix, but couldn't. 
I hope that anyone can help me.

Thank you very much and regards.

Comment: Restore a backup. Or explain what you did to make it give this error, and undo that.

Comment: same problem here :(

Answer (score 11):

We had the same issue, turns out there is a problem with the latest version (2.0.3) of the vsts-team-calendar extension:

https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/issues/260

"As soon as this extension was pushed out, all the Team Projects disappeared from the web portal in the project collections with the extension. You will get an error on the page, "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key". Other project collections without the extension work as expected. Disabling the extension will resolve the problem."

When removed, problem was solved.

Comment: Sweet! This totally works. By the way, how'd you come across this solution? Our guys spent hours on this and couldn't figure anything out until I came across a separate discussion that referenced your response.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the issue. This **has been fixed on latest version** (2.0.9) of the **vsts-team-calendar** extension.

Response from *[ruturaj-h](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/issues/260#issuecomment-542830038)*

> version 2.0.8 includes the fix, please disable the extension, wait
>   till update is downloaded from marketplace, enable the extension when
>   you see current version to be 2.0.8.

You can check version and enable disable extension from extension management page by clicking on the extension.

[image]

To install "Team Calendar" on Azure DevOps Server/TFS, perform following steps:

- Navigate to the Azure DevOps Server Extensions page on your server.
  (For example, http://someserver/_gallery/manage)
- Click upload new extension and select the file you have just
  downloaded.
- After the extension has successfully uploaded, click Install and
  select the Team Project Collection to install into.

[image]